# Given suffix array and a pattern, search if given pattern exists

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, array

> Given a suffix array for a word, check if a pattern (consecutive chars) exists.
>
> Example:
>
> A suffix array constructed for "ameya" should return true for "ame" but false for "foo" or false for "ameyp".
>
> This algoritm is case sensitive.

I'm looking for code-review, best practices and optimizations.

```
public final class SuffixArrayPatternMatch {

    private final String[] suffixArray;

    public SuffixArrayPatternMatch(String[] suffixArray) {
        this.suffixArray = suffixArray;
    }

    /**
     * Returns  0, if the string starts with the pattern.
     * Returns  1, if the string is greater than 1.
     * Returns -1, if the string is smaller than pattern.  
     * 
     * 
     * @param str           the string to be matched with the pattern.
     * @param pattern       the pattern to be searched in the string
     * @return              -1, 0, or 1.
     */
    private int compare(String str, String pattern) {
        int length = str.length() < pattern.length() ? str.length() : pattern.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) < pattern.charAt(i)) return -1;
            if (str.charAt(i) > pattern.charAt(i)) return  1;
        }

        // string was greater than myself. thus return 0.
        return str.length() < pattern.length() ? -1 : 0;
    }


    private boolean binarySearch(int lb, int hb, String pattern) {
        if (lb > hb) {
            return false;
        }
        int mid = (lb + hb) / 2;

        int match = compare(suffixArray[mid], pattern);

        if (match == 0) return true;

        if (match > 0) { 
            return binarySearch(lb, mid -1, pattern);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(mid + 1, hb, pattern);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks the pattern if present in the string
     * 
     * @param pattern   the pattern to be searched in the string
     * @return          true if pattern is found else false.
     */
    public boolean search (String pattern) {
        return binarySearch(0, suffixArray.length - 1, pattern);
    }
}


public class SuffixArrayPatternArrayTest {

    @Test
    public void testTrue() {
        String[] suffix = {"a", "ameya", "eya", "meya", "ya"};
        SuffixArrayPatternMatch sapm = new SuffixArrayPatternMatch(suffix);

        for (int i = 0; i < suffix.length; i++) {
            assertTrue(sapm.search(suffix[i]));
        }

        assertTrue(sapm.search("mey"));
        assertTrue(sapm.search("ame"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFalse() {
        String[] suffix = {"a", "ameya", "eya", "meya", "ya"};
        SuffixArrayPatternMatch sapm = new SuffixArrayPatternMatch(suffix);

        assertFalse(sapm.search("foo"));
        assertFalse(sapm.search("yap"));
        assertFalse(sapm.search("ameyap"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a hidden implementation requirement that the suffix be sorted (i.e. binary search), you should sort the array before assigning it to the member variable.

Your `compare` implementation differs from that of the String class in that it returns 0 if `str` starts with `pattern`. Why not code it that way?

```
private int compare(String str, String pattern) {
     return str.startsWith(pattern) ? 0 : str.compareTo(pattern);
}
```

Comment: A suffix array is sorted by definition. Instead of sorting, I would throw an exception if the suffix array is not sorted.

Comment: @mjolka in the same boat as @rolfl, didn't realize this was an actual data structure. In light of such, an `exception` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Right, talk about confusing. This code is written about 'suffix search', but all it does is prefix-search. Suffix happens at the end of the word, prefix happens at the beginning.

Comment: It's checking if the pattern is a prefix of any element in the suffix array. `p` is a substring of `s` if and only if `p` is a prefix of a suffix of `s`.

Comment: @mjolka - Oh, you're right. I have not heard of the concept of a "suffix array" before. I see it is a [well-defined structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array). This is a clear indication that the question does not contain enough detail about the problem being solved. I don't think I will delete my answer, it makes it clear that naming is a problem in the code.